# cakephp route all pages to a certain view

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.0

Sorry for the not very descriptive title, couldn't find a way to put it.

I am developing a site where users can build their own shops with products. What I would like to do is to have all shop names be called something like:

site.com/shop1

site.com/my_shop_name

site.com/john_shop

etc

of course I don't want to interfere with other routes like /shops/add, /shops/edit, /products/view/product_name etc.

Since shops are created dynamically I cannot write down all routes as routes.php.

Is there a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am working in similar type project. what i did is we have fixed templates. so in templats's db table I had given those templates a perticualr name. Those templates will be in view like this

app/view/Home/aglet.ctp
app/view/Home/gondor.ctp

app/view/About/aglet.ctp
app/view/About/gondor.ctp

app/view/Layout/aglet/default.ctp
app/view/Layout/gondor/default.ctp

app/webroot/aglet/css/123.css
app/webroot/aglet/js/123.js

when someone will come to site , u can get that domain name usign HTTP_HOST. by name You can get domain_id and by domain hasOne template you can get template forlder.
 so to rendring view you can get by

```
$this->layout = $result['Template][foldername].DS.'default'
```

and

```
$this->render('/Home'.DS.$result['Template][foldername]);
```

in such way, you can define routs. like

```
Router::conncet('/Homepage',array('controller'=>'Home','action'=>'home'));
```

so if you have 6 pages you have to create 6 routs. that's all

Comment: I don't it'll work for him or not, but it worked for me. thanks man